# Columns width with Tablesorter+filter

Tags: tablesorter

While using the tablesorter css default theme, if I avoid to set the table width I get a nice table with all columns perfectly adjusted to the longest field.
BUT, If I add filter widget, all columns appear much wider than before, with a lot of empty space. Sometimes text columns are wraped, while others look nearly empty.

Can this behavior be avoided? Thanks!

Comment: Can you please share an example? You can use [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/abkNM/) as a basis for your code.

Comment: [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/abkNM/687/) I removed the css theme to avoid the width:100% parameter. This would be the desired column width distribution. But when I add the filter widget, see it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/abkNM/688/), column widths are too long and don't fit the fields.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The filter inputs inherent size depends on the browser, the version and your OS. So simply adding an input into a table cell will stretch it to that size. But you can set a `max-width` or `width` using css.

I've [updated the demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/abkNM/691/) you shared, with this css to show how the theme set style can be overridden:

```
.tablesorter, .tablesorter .tablesorter-filter {
    width: auto;
}
```

If you want the columns narrower, just set the input width as a pixel size ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/abkNM/692/)):

```
.tablesorter {
    width: auto;
}
.tablesorter .tablesorter-filter {
    width: 50px;
}
```

---

Update: if you need different width inputs, try this css ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/abkNM/694/)):

```
.tablesorter .tablesorter-filter-row td:nth-child(4n+1) .tablesorter-filter {
    width: 80px;
}
.tablesorter .tablesorter-filter-row td:nth-child(4n+2) .tablesorter-filter {
    width: 40px;
}
```

where the `4` in `4n` is the number of columns in the table (one-based-index)

Answer (score 3):

You can change size of each text boxe using the following style

```
#sites_list_table .tablesorter-filter-row td>[data-column="1"] {
    width: 100px;
}
#sites_list_table .tablesorter-filter-row td>[data-column="4"] {
    width: 100px;
}
#sites_list_table .tablesorter-filter-row td>[data-column="6"] {
    width: 100px;
}
```

(`#sites_list_table` is the id of the table)

Answer (score 1):

If you have unbroken strings in your table data you may need to try changing:

```
table.tablesorter tbody td {
    color: #3D3D3D;
    padding: 4px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

To:

```
table.tablesorter tbody td {
    color: #3D3D3D;
    padding: 4px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    vertical-align: top;
    max-width:400px;
    word-wrap:break-word;
}
```

(this worked for me in Chrome and IE11)

Answer (score 0):

Another way to get rid of some empty space is setting the width to 100%

```
.tablesorter .tablesorter-filter {
    width: 100%;
}
```